# Shell Script - Fibonacci

Tags: shell, fibonacci

the code below cannot make the fibonacci sequence more than 93 sequences, how can i solve this? I would like you to do with any number

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Program to Find Fibonacci Series"
  echo "How many number of terms to be generated ?"
  read n
  x=0
  y=1
  i=2
  echo "Fibonacci Series up to $n terms :"
  echo "$x"
  echo "$y"
  while [ $i -lt $n ]
  do
      i=`expr $i + 1 `
      z=`expr $x + $y `
      echo "$z"
      x=$y
      y=$z
  done
```

Comment: `Fibonacci(94) > 2**64 = UInt64.MaxValue` so you have *integer overflow*

Comment: bash can do arithmetic, you don't need to call out to `expr`. See 
[Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)
and [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic)
in the manual.

Comment: @Pinguino: _how can i solve this_ : Use a programming language which can handle integers of arbitrray lang.  _I would like you to do with **any** number_ : If you really mean **any** in the English sense of the word, don't forget to buy a computer with infinite amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "bc" command (an interactive algebraic language with arbitrary precision) to get past numeric limits of the shell. Here is the re-write of your while loop:

```
while [[ $i -lt $n ]]
do
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
    z=$( bc <<< "$x + $y" )
    echo "$z"
    x=$y
    y=$z
done
```

On Debian/Ubuntu/RHEL/CentOS systems, install the optional "bc" package.